# Excel's base color scheme was replaced by pinks, purples, and blues. How do I revert to the "normal" MS color scheme?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, colors

Excel decided it wanted to shake things up and the only color schemes available to me are very bright pinks, purples, and blues, rather than the standard greens, reds, and blues of the "normal" Excel color palette.

This also only applies to a single workbook. Opening a new workbook shows the standard MS scheme. The scheme can be seen here:

[image: Scheme]

My boss hates this new, technicolor workbook. I am not sure how to change it back to normal. Send help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to revert your colors - go to the Page Layout tab and use the `Colors` dropdown in the Theme section; there you can change the color palettes available in the Design tab. If the colors you want are not available, you may also need to change your Theme from the same location.

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick. I will give you the credit in six minutes.

Comment: No problem! and thank you